# Mapping to create dummy variables

Tags: python-3.x

In [88]: df_reason_date_modified['Education'].value_counts()

Out[88]:

1    583

3     73

2     40

4      4

Name: Education, dtype: int64

I want to map this by creating dummy variable 0,1 from the output.

I used this code:df_reason_date_modified['Education']=df_reason_date_modified['Education'].map({1:0,2:1,3:1,4:1})

but i am getting a warning message as in the attached image

[C:\Users\Yuonsung Ventures\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy10F.jpg)

Comment: you want to create one column on the dataframe for each unique value, or you want to create one single column numbering the dummy values like 0,1,2,3,4... ?

Answer (score 0):

you could create a dictionary from unique values if you want to create just one column with dummy values(1,2,3,4,5...) or you can usepd.get_dummies if you want to create one column for each unique value in the Education column

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Education':['a','b','c','c','c','d'],
    'Grades': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})

education_to_dummy = {education:dummy_index
        for dummy_index, education
        in enumerate(df["Education"].unique())}

df['Dummy_Education']=df['Education'].map(education_to_dummy)
print(df)
```

Would create

```
  Education  Grades  Dummy_Education
0         a       1                0
1         b       2                1
2         c       3                2
3         c       4                2
4         c       5                2
5         d       6                3
```

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Education':['a','b','c','c','c','d'],
    'Grades': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})

print(pd.get_dummies(df['Education']))
```

Would create:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0
2  0  0  1  0
3  0  0  1  0
4  0  0  1  0
5  0  0  0  1
```